# Replace "," to ";" in single line of text column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, calculated-column

I need an advice on the following situation.

I have column that is single line of text which stores email addresses separated by comma (the value is created by lookup table).

Example:

```
ABC@yahoo.com,123@yahoo.com,XYZ@yahoo.com
```

I want to convert it to:

```
ABC@yahoo.com;123@yahoo.com;XYZ@yahoo.com..
```

I need to convert it so that I can send an email out.

Any existing solution or advice will be appreciated.

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value is created by lookup table"?? How the string is generated in comma separated format??

Comment: There is a list include column Division and column name which is already populated. In the nintex form, when user select the Division match the list, it will pick the name on the column and list it on the column Rep Name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SharePoint Designer to set the single line of text column to store lookup column email addresses, you don't need to set the text column.

In SharePoint Designer workflow, we can return the lookup field as "Lookup Values, Comma Delimited" (works in 2010 workflow and 2013 workflow).

[image]

You can send email using this look up column value.

Comment: Sorry I need your advice. I don't see the screenshot you provide. I am using Nintex forms for office 365.

Comment: I don't see the screenshot you shown. I am using Nintex forms for office 365. The column is based on whatever the division selected and the lookup with refer to the table of the column and it match, it will added to the multiple line text.